# What are the periodic points of period 5 of $f(x) = x^2+1$?

Tags: dynamical-systems

What are the periodic points of period 5 for $f(x) = x^2+1$ if $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$?

Solving the full equation for $f^5(x)$ seems like a nightmare, but I'm not sure of any better way.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Note that $f(x) = x + \bigl(x - \frac{1}{2}\bigr)^2 + \frac{3}{4}$.

Answer (score 2):

For all $x \in \Bbb R$ 
$$ 
 |f(x)| = f(x) = x^2 + 1 = 
\underbrace{(|x|-1)^2 + |x|}_{> 0} + |x| > |x|
$$
therefore $f$ has no real periodic points of *any* order.

Answer (score 1):

There are no real periodic points. We have

$$((((x^2+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2+1)^2+1 = f_5 (x)$$

For all real $x$, $f_5(x) \geq f_5(0)= 677$. So if we require $f_5(x) = x$, then $x$ must be at least 677. However for $x  \geq 677$, always $f_5(x) > x$.

Answer (score 0):

[Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((((x%5E2%2B1)%5E2%2B1)%5E2%2B1)%5E2%2B1)%5E2%2B1%3Dx) finds no real roots.  It is a $32$nd degree polynomial, so there should be $32$ roots.  The plot is below,  The imaginary cube roots of $1$ are two of them.  The others do not seem to have a simple form.

[image]

Comment: Try to check whether $f$ has periodic points of period 3. If yes, Sharkovski's Theorem guarantees the existence of periodic points of all periods. If there are no points of period 3 - everything is possible.

Comment: @szw1710:  there are no real periodic points of period $3$.  Two of the imaginary ones are the complex cube roots of $-1$.  The others seem to have no simple form.